# Retrieve List from listView.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, .net, linq, listview

I'd like to do a simple thing : Retrieve a ListView ItemsSource to use Linq on it and give it again to the Listview, like :

```
LV1.ItemsSource = LV1.ItemsSource.Where(x => x.age > 10);
```

Can I do it somehow ?

Comment: You could just add a `.ToList()` at the end there to create a copy.

Comment: Nah, I already tried that, ItemsSource does not accept ToList() :/

Comment: Oh right, it’s just an untyped `IEnumerable`. In that case you can do `.Cast<ItemType>().Where(x => …).ToList()` (where `ItemType` is the type of your items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it to the type and then bind,

```
var filterResult =  LV1.ItemsSource as List<yourclass>;
LV1.ItemsSource =filterResult .Where(x => x.age > 10);
```